# MediaPlayer can not play file when file name contains Special characters

Tags: android, file, audio, android-mediaplayer

my audio file path was

```
I/MediaPlayer: setDataSource:/storage/emulated/0/XXX/Audios/044046ffffff870627ffffffb171ffffff8b0171ffffffceffffffccffffffa60effffffa7497dffffff88ffffffbeffffff9f1effffffc747ffffffbd4f62ffffff9a4a392b54/005final - 2019:3:11 上午12.23.mp3
```

then I got the error

```
 E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
 E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
 V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
 V/MediaPlayer: cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
 E/MediaPlayerNative: pause called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
 E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
```

when I rename about this file, MediaPlayer play this file succeed!

Who can tell me why？

Is it related to`：`?

because of the Linux file system has this warning
[image]

when I use name contains `:` the audio cannot play and get the error, remove `:`it succeed!

Comment: Can you show the code where you're creating the `MediaPlayer`? You may need to encode the URI

Comment: Post your relevant code

Comment: these characters have other meanings to the file system or to the command prompt (where file naming rules were originally created.)

Comment: the path was not set because of those special characters and the pause() method was called on the media player with path null or unset. Which will result in state error